# Not able to get swift data from kotlin repo

Tags: swift, realm, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kmm project, I am able to get the data from the kotlin version, but for iOS not. I am getting an exception break with code: Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

The data from the repo that I am trying to get:

```
suspend fun getRestaurantsOrders(): CommonFlow<List<Order>> {
        val userId = appService.currentUser!!.id
        val restaurant = realm.query<Restaurant>("userID = $0", userId).first().find()!!
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            realm.query<Order>("restaurantID = $0 && totalQuantity > 0 SORT(discount DESC)", restaurant._id.toString())
                .asFlow().map {
                    it.list
                }.asCommonFlow()
        }
    }
```

The way that I am trying to get data from ios:

```
func getOrdersList()
    {
        Task{
            do{
                try await repo.getRestaurantsOrders().watch(block: {orders in

                    self.restaurantActiveOrdersList = orders as! [Order] //breaks here

                })
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
I am new at swift, thanks in advance!

Comment: Best practice here on SO is to include some troubleshooting. It's great you've indicated the line that's failing but there are a number of vars in your code which, to us, are undefined. For example is the call to `getRestaurantsOrders()` actually working? If so, what happens within that section of code? I see your force unwrapping an optional here `appService.currentUser!!.id` which is generally not a good idea; is `userId` valid? Please step through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way ensuring vars are properly populated. Update the question with your results.

Comment: Hello Jay, thank you for the response! The problem is that in the method I used withContext(Dispatchers.Default) in the kotlin method, do you have any clue why this is the issue?

Comment: No because there's not enough info in the question. I would suggest first determining if `userId` and `restaurant` are nil, if so, that's part of the issue. Then, I would change that return to assigning it to a var `val someData = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { }` followed after the closure with a `return someData` and then comment out the code within the closure `{ realm.query<Order>...}`. etc This is what I mean by troubleshooting - try to isolate the issue so when you post the question you're providing us enough info to help.

Comment: There are not nil, the issue happens here: `val someData = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { } `

Comment: Based on your comment, I don't think this issue has anything to do with Swift since it's the Kotlin repo that's crashing, not the swift code. I would check the repo itself. Not sure there's much else we can do here since that code as-is shouldn't crash.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem with Kotlin, The problem its that I am using `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` in this case, but I am not able to understand why that should be a problem

Comment: what is the difference from `repo.getRestaurantsOrders().watch{}` and `repo.getRestaurantsOrders().watch(block: {})`

Comment: what does block do?